# Using controller to update attributes of another controller and mass-assignment problems in rails 4.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mass-assignment, update-attributes

I've just updated my rails app from 3.2.8 to 4.1.1. I did the required alterations to make the transition as smooth as possible. I used to use one controller to update the attributes of another controller like this:

```
     1. def check_rates
     2. @page_title = "Checkout"
     3. @order = Order.new(params[:order])
     4. @order.customer_ip = request.remote_ip


     5. populate_order


     6. if @order.save

     7.  session[:order_id] = @order.id
     8. @order.order_items.each do |order_item|
     9. @member = Member.find(order_item.member_id)    

    10. **@member.update_attributes(
    11. :order_id =>@order.id)**  
    12. end      
    13. respond_to do |format|
    14. format.html{ redirect_to :action => 'rate_response' } 
    15. format.js
    16. end

    17. else
    18. flash[:notice] = "Error saving buyers address." 

    19. respond_to do |format|
    20. format.html{  render :action => 'index' } 
    21. format.js

    22. end
    23. end
    24.   end
```

The lines 10 and 11 throw an exception:

```
*WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Member: order_id*
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me to solve this issue. I do not use 'attr_accessible' anymore. I use 'params.require(model_name).permit(*attributes) for each of the controller. But what if one controller is used to update attributes of another?

```
MemberController:
 def member_params
 params.require(member).permit(:city_town, :country, :county_region, :description, 
 :name,:house_flat, :image,  :mob_tel, :postcode_index, :street,
 :image_temp,:latitude,:longitude, :pw_reset_code, :order_id)
 end 


 CheckoutController:
   def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:ship_to_house_number,
  :ship_to_street,:ship_to_city,:ship_to_postal_code,
  :ship_to_country,:sender,:receiver,:service_name,:cart_id,
  :ship_to_first_name, :ship_to_last_name,:email, :phone_number,:company_name,:county_region ) 
   end
  def member_params
  params.require(member).permit(:order_id) 
  end    

Member model:
belongs_to :order

Order model:
has_many :members
```

Comment: I guess you have to deal this with `accepts_nested_atributes_for`.Can you post your models and `strong params` method in the `controller`?

Comment: Please update it in the question and also add your Models.

Comment: I did. Please have a look at it.

Comment: What happens when you you remove `order_id` from the `permitted params`?

Comment: @user1811541 in line 10-11 you have simply passed order_id. You havent permitted it or used member_params method inside update call and hence your error

Comment: How to do it? Can you send me a code example please.

Comment: The `check_rates` method belongs to which controller?

Comment: Pavan:     If I remove it, i get the same error message.

Comment: The 'check_rates' belongs to CheckoutController.

Comment: CheckoutController doesn't have Model or table in a database. I created it for checkout purposes. If you need to have a closer look, I will send it in full.

Comment: What happens when you just give it like `@member.update_attributes(member_params)` instead of `@member.update_attributes(:order_id =>@order.id)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a very silly mistake: in 'params.require(model_name).permit(*args)', I haven't used the   model name as symbol:

```
 params.require(member).permit(*args) ----- WRONG 
 params.require(:member).permit(*args) ---- WRIGHT
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error `*WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Member: order_id*` clearly tell that you need to pass order_id in your set of permitted attributes. Inside your `members_controller.rb` you could make a private method memeber_params and do this:

```
def member_params
  params.require(:member).permit(*attributes, :order_id) #need to add order_id here
end
```

For more information on [strong parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html)

**Or**

As `Pavan` said if you are using `nested_attributes_for` then your member_params will be:

```
def member_params
  params.require(:member).permit(*attributes, :order_attributes{order_attributes})
end
```

For more information on [accepts_nested_attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

**Edit**

if you look at your line no. 10-11 you have

**@member.update_attributes(
:order_id =>@order.id)**

You are simply passing order_id into the update call. **You haven't permitted order_id**

You need to do: **@member.update_attributes(member_params)**